# Bash: if conditional clause while iterating over a 2-dimensional properties file

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, if-statement, properties-file

I have a data structure defined by **item[i]** -- contains -- > **subitem[k]**. I want to write a small bash script which parses subitems and items executes an action on hitting a specific subitem.

My **sampletext.properties** file is as such:

```
Item1.subitem1=tom
Item1.subitem2=bob
Item2.subitem1=alice
Item2.subitem2=cindy
```

Overcoming the absence of 2-dimensional arrays in Bash, I wrote two functions, one for getting the value of a key and one for counting the occurrences of a string.

I then build a for loop for parsing the items and I try to include a IF-clause to hit "bob" and say something. Unfortunately, the script is not seeing bob and it seems like the IF-clause is not working:

```
#!/bin/bash

# The input text file 
PROPERTY_FILE=sampletext.properties

#Defining a function to get the value of a key
function getProperty {
   PROP_KEY=$1
   PROP_VALUE=`cat $PROPERTY_FILE | grep "$PROP_KEY" | cut -d'=' -f2 | tr -d '\n'`
   echo $PROP_VALUE
}

# Counting the number of subitem1 entries
function countsubitem1 {
  toolsnumber=`cat $PROPERTY_FILE | grep "Item[0-9].subitem1" | wc -l`
  echo $toolsnumber
}
countsubitem1


for (( i=1; i<=$(countsubitem1); i++))
do
  subitem1=`getProperty "Item$i.subitem1"`
  subitem2=`getProperty "Item$i.subitem2"`
  echo item$i:$(getProperty "Item$i.subitem1") # Testing the getProperty function again
  echo subitem2:$subitem2 # Testing the for loop and the getProperty function
  if [[ "$subitem2" == "bob" ]]; then
    echo "I see bob!"
  else
    echo "No bob here!"
  fi  
done
```

What I get launching the script:

```
2
item1:tom
subitem2:bob
No bob here!
item2:alice
subitem2:cindy
No bob here!
```

What I expect:

```
./samplebash.sh
2
item1:tom
subitem2:bob
I see bob!
item2:alice
subitem2:cindy
No bob here!
```

I tried several alterations of the IF-clause:

```
 if [ "$subitem2" == "bob" ]; then
```

```
  if [ '$subitem2' == 'bob' ]; then
```

but I always get the 'No bob here!' message.

Comment: The alternatives you tried, don't make much sense, but did you verify that the value stored in `subitem2` does not contain a trailing space?

Comment: Don't you have Bash 4+ to use associative arrays rather than inefficiently opening closing and parsing the whole file when addressing each property by key?

Comment: Hi user1934428, thank you for your time. I tried to add | sed 's/ *$//g' to the PROP_VALUE definition for removing an ending trailing space but unfortunately I don't see any difference

Comment: What about trailing `\r`?

Comment: Pet peeve - [UUoC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @William Pursell for the hint!

Adding a `| tr -d '\r'` cleaned the string and it parsed correctly.

I now obtain:

```
item1subitem1:tom
subitem2:bob
I see bob!
item2subitem2:alice
subitem2:cindy
No bob here!
```

with the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# The input text file 
PROPERTY_FILE=sampletext.properties

#Defining a function to get the value of a key
function getProperty {
   PROP_KEY=$1
   PROP_VALUE=`cat $PROPERTY_FILE | grep "$PROP_KEY" | cut -d'=' -f2 | tr -d '\n' | tr -d '\r'`
   echo $PROP_VALUE
}

# Counting the number of subitem1 entries
function countsubitem1 {
  toolsnumber=`cat $PROPERTY_FILE | grep "Item[0-9].subitem1" | wc -l`
  echo $toolsnumber
}


for (( i=1; i<=$(countsubitem1); i++))
do
  subitem1=`getProperty "Item$i.subitem1"`
  subitem2=`getProperty "Item$i.subitem2"`
  echo item"$i"subitem$i:$(getProperty "Item$i.subitem1") # Testing the getProperty function again
  echo subitem2:$subitem2 # Testing the for loop and the getProperty function
  if [[ "$subitem2" == "bob" ]]; then
    echo "I see bob!"
  else
    echo "No bob here!"
  fi  
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Please consider this code:

```
readarray -t arr < "$PROPERTY_FILE"
getitem () {
    for i in "${arr[@]}"; {
        read item subitem value <<< ${i//[.=]/ }
        case ${1:-1}${2:-2} in $item$subitem|${item}2|1$subitem)
            echo "item=$item subitem=$subitem value=$value";;
        esac
    }
}
```

Usage

```
$ getitem Item1 
item=Item1 subitem=subitem1 value=tom
item=Item1 subitem=subitem2 value=bob

$ getitem Item1 subitem2
item=Item1 subitem=subitem2 value=bob

$ getitem '' subitem1
item=Item1 subitem=subitem1 value=tom
item=Item2 subitem=subitem1 value=alice

$ getitem Item2
item=Item2 subitem=subitem1 value=alice
```

Answer (score 1):

Using associative arrays

```
#!/bin/bash

# The input text file 
PROPERTY_FILE=sampletext.properties


# Load the properties file
#
declare -A properties

loadProperties() {
    local key value

    if [[ "${#properties[@]}" -eq 0 ]]
    then
        # Lazy load the properties file
        # Strip Windows-style CR as we go
        #
        while IFS='=' read -r key value
        do
            properties[$key]="$value"

        done < <(tr -d '\r' <"$PROPERTY_FILE")
    fi
}


# Get the value of a key
#
getProperty() {
    local key="$1"

    loadProperties
    echo "${properties[$key]}"
}

    
# Count the number of "subitem1" items
#
countsubitem1() {
    loadProperties
    printf "%s\n" "${!properties[@]}" | awk -F. '$2 == "subitem1"' | wc -l
}
```

Now you can use the functions and get the expected values

```
countsubitem1
2

getProperty Item1.subitem2
bob

i=1
subitem1="$(getProperty "Item$i.subitem1")"
printf "%s\n" "$subitem1"
tom
```

Don't use the deprecated `function` keyword to declare a function. Aim to use lowercase variable names so that yours can't clash with standard variables such as `$PATH`. Use `$( ... )` instead of backticks to enclose a value that needs to be executed.